# Test Runner is not able to locate the test steps in cucumber selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber

Here is the the code for the test runner

```
package Runner;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
import io.cucumber.testng.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)

@CucumberOptions(  monochrome = true,
        features ="src/test/resources/Features/tc1",
        glue = "HuntingtonGlue",
        tags= "@tc1"

//        dryRun = true
)

public class TestNgCucumberRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {


    @BeforeSuite(alwaysRun = true)
    public void beforeSuiteApiBase() throws Exception {

        if (System.getProperty("os.name").toUpperCase().contains("WINDOWS")) {
            try {
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM chromedriver.exe.exe /T");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

The runner is unable to find the test steps and is giving the following error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test'.
> No tests found for given includes: [Runner.TestNgCucumberRunner](filter.includeTestsMatching)
```

The tags, feature file and glue class locations are accurate, any help is appreciated thanks.